# List of materials in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

There is a folder in Unity project, where some material files are located. These materials can be assigned to various meshes etc. I want to have a list of these materials and to loop over this list in Update().

Is there a way to maintain this list automatically - I add a material file to folder, and corresponding Material object is added to this list?

Comment: Do you want to do this for editor mode or for run-time?

Comment: Umair's question is really good, please answer it. However if you just want do it in run-time you can create a material array and then change the index and assign the new material to the mesh.

Comment: I want to have this list in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cycle through folders and find every file with `.mat` extension and next load it manually.

Take a look at c# `File` and `Directory` classes in `System.IO` for getting names of material files.
Next load them by `Resources.Load()` i-e:

```
Resources.Load("Material/Night_Sky", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

**EDIT:**
The above solution will only works in EDITOR as you can't get names of materials with `System.IO` in builds. `Resources.Load` will work fine in builds but you will need names of materials.
As mentioned in comments `Resources.LoadAll()` will do the job.
Additionally for both `Resources.Load()` and `Resources.LoadAll()`, you need to put all materials you want to load into `Resources` folders i-e:

If path to your materials is: `Assets\Resources\Materials` you need to use:

```
Resources.LoadAll("Materials")
```

Helpful links to documentation:
[Resources.LoadAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html)
[LoadingResourcesatRuntime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html)

Comment: Sorry, i think this will work only in editor. But if you will keep all materials in one folder you can use Resources.LoadAll().
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html

Comment: Theres also Resources.LoadAll() https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html * beaten by @Krajca 18secs :)

Comment: I want to have this list in runtime.

Comment: Loading resources works in builds. Look at this for more info:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. `Resources.Load` works in the Editor and Build too. You need to modify this answer. Most stuff are wrong. **"Take a look at c# File and Directory classes in System.IO for getting names of material files."**  System.IO has nothing to do with `Resources.Load` and will not work with `Resources.Load`. You also have to remove ".mat" from your code. When you put the file extension, it won't work. You should also put in your answer the the OP must place the Material folder in the `Resources` folder which is in `Assets\Resources`.

Comment: Like i wrote in first comment it should work in editor. To use `Resources.Load` you need to have a name for material you want to load. As question is about automatically way - looking for files in directories for `*.mat` should help with that.

Comment: You made a comment about it not working in the runtime. You either deleted or modified it. That's why I aid it works in both Editor and Runtime. Your answer is half way correct. My comment is for you to fix it. Again, you can't look in the `Resources` directory with `System.IO`. It won't work with `Resources.Load`. Last time I checked it doesn't work with `System.IO`. You should fix that as well. Doing that in the Editor will work but after you build it, it won't. As for loading all of them, `Resources.LoadAll()` should do it like you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I think it really could be some way confusing. Thanks for clarifying that.